# Regex to add part of string to end of line in my Text Editor

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, text-editor

I'm using Sublime 2 Text Editor which accepts RegEx search and replace. I'm attempting to find a whole line, then replace that whole line with a string found in the line itself.

This is my text that I am searching:

```
 strEventID = CheckForNull(reader("
 strEventKey = CheckForNull(reader("
 strEventTitle = CheckForNull(reader("
```

I want to this text to become:

```
 strEventID = CheckForNull(reader("EventID"))
 strEventKey = CheckForNull(reader("EventKey"))
 strEventTitle = CheckForNull(reader("EventTitle"))
```

I know that FIND: (^.*$) will match the whole line and I can REPLACE with $1 and add to that line manually, but I can't figure out how to add part of the string back in.

Comment: I'm not familiarized with sublime, but I will give what would be for notepad++ and you test it, if it work, i will post it as an answer: try: on find `(str)([a-zA-Z]*)([\s=]*)(CheckForNull\(reader\(")` and on replace: `$1$2$3$4$2"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

`(str(\w*).*)$`

replace with `$1$2"))` or `$1$2"\)\)` here in notepad++.

Make sure the ". matches newline" is unchecked

**old answer:**

Try:

`^(str(.*\b).*)$`
replace with `$1$2"))`.

I don't have sublimeText with me right now, but this test http://regex101.com/r/hM2oX2/1 says group 1 is the whole line, and group 2 is your first match. concatenate...

Comment: +1 learning new things every day here. I did not know about `\b` :)

Comment: tks! i think we're getting close. It does properly add the EventID minus the str, but then it adds the whole string after that to give the following result:

strEventID = CheckForNull(reader("EventID = CheckForNull(reader"))

Comment: Yes, that is because I used an "ungreedy modifier" in regex101. I changed the solution, might help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Sublime, you can use the following regular expression: `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

```
Find What: str(\w+).*\K
Replace With: $1"))
```